# Dynamic web module version 6.0 does not allow deploying in Tomcat 10.1

Tags: java, eclipse, tomcat

Using Eclipse IDE for Enterprise Java and Web Developers 2023-03.

I create a New Dynamic Web Project, and choose Dynamic Web module version 6.0.
The resulting project does not offer the possibility to deploy in a server (Tomcat 10.1)

While the same process, choosing Dynamic Web module version 5.0 works fine.

Hoping someone can actually help me on this.. Thank you in Advance!

Comment: Please retry with 2023-06 M2, https://www.eclipse.org/downloads/packages/release/2023-06/m2/eclipse-ide-enterprise-java-and-web-developers .